# I can not assign GetX state management value to integer

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, state-management

I want to create BottomNavigationBar with GetX state management. I keep my page index on my GetXController.

```
class PagerController extends GetxController {
  RxInt pageIndex = 0.obs;
  changePageTo(int index) {
    pageIndex.value = index;
  }
}
```

Here is my BottomNavigationBar widget. It is stateless.

```
BottomNavigationBar(
      showSelectedLabels: false,
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      selectedItemColor: Palette.kSelectedCategoryColor,
      unselectedItemColor: Palette.kUnselectedCategoryTextColor,
      elevation: 0,
      enableFeedback: false,
      currentIndex: controller.pageIndex.value,
      items: items,
      onTap: (index) => controller.changePageTo(index),
    );
```

onTap my body is changing. But my bottom navigation bar's active icon color is not changing. In my opinion it causes for currentIndex property. I put `controller.pageIndex.value`, but it is not listening value, it renders only one time. How to solve it?

Comment: is pageIndex value changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your bottom navigation bar with Obx

Answer (score 1):

First of all, u should change `pageIndex`'s type from `RxInt` to `int` or just `var` (adding `.obs` is enough).

Second of all, in order for the `BottomNavigationBar` to update, u need to wrap it in `Obx()`, for example :

```
Obx(() => BottomNavigationBar(
      showSelectedLabels: false,
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      selectedItemColor: Palette.kSelectedCategoryColor,
      unselectedItemColor: Palette.kUnselectedCategoryTextColor,
      elevation: 0,
      enableFeedback: false,
      currentIndex: controller.pageIndex.value,
      items: items,
      onTap: (index) => controller.changePageTo(index),
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use GetBuilder. I past my DashBoard page code by replacing your navBar code with. In this case, don't event need to put obs(in controller) and Obx(in view).

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<DashBoardController>(builder: (controller) {
      return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: IndexedStack(
              index: controller.pageIndex,
              children: [
                HomeScreen(),
                MeScreen(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              showSelectedLabels: false,
              showUnselectedLabels: false,
              selectedItemColor: Palette.kSelectedCategoryColor,
              unselectedItemColor: Palette.kUnselectedCategoryTextColor,
              elevation: 0,
              enableFeedback: false,
              currentIndex: controller.pageIndex,
              items: items,
              onTap: controller.changePageTo,
            ),
          );
          
    });
  }
```

In dash_board_controller.dart, we got changePageTo method in the controller. It executes a update which does the page refresh work.

```dart
class DashBoardController extends GetxController {
  var tabIndex = 0;

  var getToNamedList = [
    Routes.HOME,
    Routes.ME,
  ];
  final List<BottomNavigationBarItem> navTabList = <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      activeIcon: ImageIcon(
        AssetImage('assets/***.png'),
        size: 24,
      ),
      icon: ImageIcon(
        AssetImage('assets/***.png'),
        size: 24,
      ),
      label: "Home",
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      activeIcon: ImageIcon(
        AssetImage('assets/***.png'),
        size: 24,
      ),
      icon: ImageIcon(
        AssetImage('assets/***.png'),
        size: 24,
      ),
      // icon: Icon(Icons.person),
      label: "Me",
    ),
  ];

  void changePageTo(int index) {
    tabIndex = index;
    update();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With wrapping bottomnav with Obx builder. you should also call update() method in changePage method in controller.